# how to convert PEM to P7B with python

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

this works perfectly in command-line, 
 I would like to do the same using M2Crypto in Python code.

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ra.crt -out ra-ca.p7b -certfile ca.crt.
```