# How can I use Python to output a certificates-only PKCS#7

Tags: python, ruby, openssl

I'm implementing a [SCEP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nourse-scep-17) server in Python. The SCEP spec calls for me to respond to a `PKIOperation` with a "a certificate-only PKCS#7". Apple has a reference implementation in Ruby that does the following.

```
require 'openssl'

@@root_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("ca_cert.pem"))
@@ra_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("ra_cert.pem"))

scep_certs = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new()
scep_certs.type="signed"
scep_certs.certificates=[@@root_cert, @@ra_cert]

File.open('from_ruby.der', 'w') { |file| file.write(scep_certs.to_der)}
```

That code correctly outputs a PCKS7 DER file that contains both the CA and RA certificates. I'm trying to port this code to Python. I'm using the M2Crypto library for access to OpenSSL. I am struggling with the fact that [M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7-class.html) does not have a `certificates` method. So far I have come up with the following.

```
from M2Crypto import X509

ca_cert = X509.load_cert('ca_cert.pem')
ra_cert = X509.load_cert('ra_cert.pem')

stack = X509.X509_Stack()
stack.push(ca_cert)
stack.push(ra_cert)

derFile = open('from_python.der', 'w')
derFile.write(stack.as_der())
```

This Python code does output a DER encoded file that does look like it contains both certs. However OpenSSL is unable to read this file.

```
openssl pkcs7 -in from_ruby.der -inform DER -print_certs
```

Prints out the certs from the Ruby script just fine, while

```
openssl pkcs7 -in from_python.der -inform DER -print_certs
```

throws this error

```
unable to load PKCS7 object
89377:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong             tag:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1315:
89377:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:827:
89377:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:747:Field=type, Type=PKCS7
```

How can I get Python to output both the CA and RA certs in the same format that Ruby is?

[I have posted the test certs I'm using as a gist.](https://gist.github.com/skabber/6336287)

Update:
I figured out the openssl command that will produce the same file.

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ca_cert.pem -certfile ra_cert.pem -out crl.der -outform DER
```

So now, how do I do that in Python. Which is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583737/how-to-convert-pem-to-p7b-with-python)

Comment: Have you looked at [M2Crypto's PKCS7 Class](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7-class.html)?

Comment: Yes I did. M2Crypto's PKCS7 class doesn't have a `certificates` method like it's Ruby counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same requirement, and ended up forking M2Crypto to add a new function that would create a degenerate PKCS7 object. https://github.com/HanSooloo/M2Crypto-martinpaljak

The steps involved were the following:

1. Fork M2Crypto from Martin Paljak's repo to a new one.
2. Modify `_pkcs7.i` SWIG interface file to add the function below.

## _pkcs7.i Modifications

```c
// Adding X.509 related header files to be able to use their data types.
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>

// Adding PKCS7_SIGNED data type to help create the degenerate data structure.
%apply Pointer NONNULL { PKCS7_SIGNED * };

// Additional interface definitions for degenerate PKCS#7 object creation.
// Inspired by the crl2p7.c file from OpenSSL.  Will need to clean up a bit for function returns.
%threadallow pkcs7_create_degenerate;
%inline %{
int pkcs7_create_degenerate(STACK_OF(X509) *cert_stack, BIO *bio) {
    int ret=1;
    PKCS7 *p7=NULL;
    PKCS7_SIGNED *p7s=NULL;
    X509_CRL *crl=NULL;
    STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crl_stack=NULL;

    if ((p7=PKCS7_new()) == NULL) goto end;
    if ((p7s=PKCS7_SIGNED_new()) == NULL) goto end;  

    p7->type=OBJ_nid2obj(NID_pkcs7_signed);
    p7->d.sign=p7s;
    p7s->contents->type=OBJ_nid2obj(NID_pkcs7_data);

    if (!ASN1_INTEGER_set(p7s->version,1)) goto end;
    if ((crl_stack=sk_X509_CRL_new_null()) == NULL) goto end;
    p7s->crl=crl_stack;
    p7s->cert=cert_stack;

    ret=i2d_PKCS7_bio(bio, p7);

end:
    p7s->cert=NULL;

    if (p7 != NULL) {
//      printf("about to free p7: ");
        PKCS7_free(p7);
//      printf("freed.\n");
    }

    return ret;

}
%}
```

## Function Details

The function takes an X509 stack pointer and BIO pointer as inputs and returns an integer indicating success.

The X509 stack pointer needs to point to a stack that contains the certificates one wishes to place in the degenerate PKCS#7 object.

The BIO pointer needs to point to an empty BIO structure that will later be populated with the PKCS#7 object.

## Python code example that uses the above function:

```py
from M2Crypto import X509, BIO, m2

sk = X509.X509_Stack()

cert = X509.load_cert('ra.crt')
num = sk.push(cert)
cert = X509.load_cert('ca.crt')
num = sk.push(cert)

# At this point, the X509 stack contains 2 certificates.
print('num: %d' %num)

# Create the BIO that will hold the PKCS#7 object.    
bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer()

# Request to create the degenerate PCKS#7 object.
ret = m2.pkcs7_create_degenerate(sk._ptr(), bio._ptr())

# Open the file for writing.
f = open('deg.p7s', 'w')

# Read from BIO and write to file.
b = bio.read()
f.write(b)

# Close the file.
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Python ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to call the OpenSSL shared library functions directly to accomplish this. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/jessepeterson/52f66951608ff8471b12).

Comment: While the link may answer the question, links change, so Stack Overflow prefers to not depend on them. [It would be better](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I have a feeling (totally untested) that it's something like this:

```
an_smime = M2Crypto.SMIME.SMIME()
an_smime.set_x509_stack(stack)
an_smime.write(M2Crypto.BIO.File('from_python.der'), pkcs7=True)
```

Comment: I've tried that with [this code](https://gist.github.com/skabber/6337516). SMIME.write() still needs to take a PKCS7 file as input. And creating a new one just outputs a blank SMIME file.